# HTML code not working in Firefox correctly

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm trying to display the following code. It's working fine in Chrome and Safari, but not working properly in Firefox. The code link: http://jsfiddle.net/nvarun123/fv4jxo4t/26/

Html code:

```
<div> 
    <a>
        <button (click)="decrement()" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: left;">
            <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" ></i></span>
        </button>
    </a>
    <input type="text" style="width:45%;" [(ngModel)]="count">
   <a>
       <button (click)="increment()" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right;">
           <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ></i></span>
       </button>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
div {
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid #CACEDB;
    width: 162px;
    height:38px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius:3px;
}

input {
    text-align: center;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border:none;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
}

button {
    height:100%; 
    border:none;    
}

button:hover {
    background-color: green;
}

button:active {
    background-color: #015191;
}
```

Comment: float: center doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

Here a trick to vertically center content in an html element.

Vertical aligns are always tricky with CSS, but this snippet will allow you to do it easily for a single line of text. Basically we use the line-height property to put an equidistant space at the top and bottom of the text. To make this work, the line height value needs to be the same as the height of the html element containing the text.

Check this

```css
p {
  border: red dotted thin;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  /* magic line */
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  One Liner
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #CACEDB;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  
  <div>
    <a>
      <button type="button" (click)="decrement()" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
      </button>
    </a>
    <span style="width:100%">1</span>
    <a>
      <button type="button" (click)="increment()" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      </button>
    </a>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

check out the snippet
Is this the way you want it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to style the input tag to set the value at the center by using text-align: center; this worked for me with your code.

```css
div {
   position:relative;
   width: 160px;
   height:38px;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
   border-radius:5px;
}
input{
   text-align: center;
}
input:focus {outline:none;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div> 
        <a>
        <button type="button" (click)="decrement()" class="btn btn-primary" style="height:100%; border:none;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
        </button>
        </a>
        <input type="text" style="width:45%;border:none;">
       <a>
        <button type="button" (click)="increment()" class="btn btn-primary" style="height:100%;float: right; ">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
        </a>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: hey is there any way the border of the box can be removed? I tried by keeping the style="border:none;". But its still not working.